# Does paperclip need RMagick gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, paperclip, rmagick

I am using paperclip gem for uploading/downloading and sizing photos in my Rails web application. I have ImageMagick installed. Do I also need the RMagick gem for my Rails app to work with ImageMagick? I am using the latest paperclip version 2.3.15

If I need RMagick, what is the best way to install RMagick gem on Windows Vista machine? Please point me to resources that walk through RMagick gem install on Windows machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need RMagick, only ImageMagick.

Look at the "requirements" section of the README: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: Thanks. I had a previous install of ImageMagick on my windows vista machine in "Program Files" folder. I replaced it with new ImageMagick install in a folder location no spaces. It works without needing RMagick.